# What's the problem with this four-transistors XOR gate?

Tags: mosfet, logic-gates

I aimed to design a XOR gate using as few transistors as possible. Eventually, I came up with this:

[image: XOR gate]

Designed and simulated [here.](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) The two terminals on the left are inputs, where the "low" voltage is 0V and the "high" voltage is 5V. The terminal on the right is 0V, aka the ground. The terminal on the bottom is the output.

As far as I've simulated, the output turns fully on/off for every input. Though, when I replace the output by a 1kΩ load, it expresses 4.9V voltage difference upon turning on; 0.1V less than ideal.

So is this really a suitable implementation of the XOR gate?

Comment: Driving an output from an input, rather than from a power supply, is usually a bad idea. Logic gates should have amplification.

Comment: If you use the MOSFET symbols with body diode you might also see a problem.

Comment: @LarsHankeln In CMOS VLSI the body terminals are not necessarily connected to the transistor sources; they are connected to supply voltages instead. There is no problem due to the body diodes here.